# Get all points in given radius

Tags: algorithm, math, godot

I'm currently making a procedural chunk-based terrain system for my game in Godot, and it works based off of positions where both x and y are integers, e.g. (10, 4) or (0, 2). When the game runs, I want all of the chunks in a given render distance (radius) around the player to be loaded. So, that would mean getting every single ordered pair in a circle where both x and y are integers and both x and y are less than or equal to the given render distance, and then saving it in some sort of array or object.

I'm pretty sure that some rendition of (x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 <= r^2 could work, but I'm really not sure how to implement that with solely integers and put that in code.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Given h, k, and r, the (x, y) values in the circle will satisfy
`h - r <= x <= h + r` and `k - r <= y <= k + r`.

Hence, the simplest way to do this is to use double for-loop with x, and y values in the range.
In the for-loop, you can use `if` to check whether (x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 <= r^2.

Example code

```
func get_chunks(h, k, r):
    var chunks = []

    var min_x = h - r
    var max_x = h + r
    var min_y = k - r
    var max_y = k + r
    
    for x in range(min_x, max_x + 1):
        for y in range(min_y, max_y + 1):
            if (x - h) * (x - h) + (y - k) * (y - k) <= r * r:
                chunks.append(Vector2(x, y))
    
    return chunks
```

Alternatively, you can use a for-loop with x value first, and calculate k ± sqrt(r^2 - (x-h)^2) with floor/ceil functions to find the y's range for the specific x.

Comment: @Stef That is Python, this is GDScript.